# react native: Icons doesnt display with the native-base library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, native-base

what is the way to use `ionicons` instead of the native-base library `Accordion icon` because i cant see the `Accordion icons` in my screen and i dont know how to fix it .
this is the link for native-base library :

[this is the link](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#accordion-def-headref)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];
export default class AccordionIconExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion dataArray={dataArray} icon="add" expandedIcon="remove" />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i didn't quite understand your question, does it show an X-square or what?  have you tried  react-native link or react-native link react-native-vector-icons or react-native link native-base?

Comment: its show me some Chinese letters .. and i didnt do react-native link coz my react ver is grate than 0.61

Comment: there is way to use Icon of the ionicons  instead of the Accordion icon ?

Comment: I dont know how you should use Ionicons, but I know you should link Icons, my react native version is greater  than 0.61 but it doesn't link Icons, you should manually do it (link react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: i did already but nothing change.. i just look for accordion list with hooks , can u show me some example of it ?

Comment: i found this snack but when i  try to run it on my device its fall and not work :
https://snack.expo.io/@bgpiggin/accordion-list